# ¿Cuál es la utilidad de la combinación de los selectores > * en CSS?

Tags: css

No entiendo muy bien qué puede indicar el `> *`

```
.grid > * {
```

Sé que el `*` es un selector universal, pero no entiendo cómo influye este símbolo de mayor que `>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La regla `.grid > *` indica que debe seleccionar todos los elementos que sean *hijos directos* del elemento con la clase `.grid`.

El selector `>` especifica que los elementos que seran afectados se encuentren directamente dentro del elemento antes del selector; pero los elementos del mismo tipo que se encuentren en un nivel mas interno ya no seran afectados.

Por ejemplo, supongamos el selector `.padre > a`, con esto estaremos seleccionando todos los elementos `a` que se encuentren dentro de `.padre`, pero unicamente si son hijos en primer nivel, es decir:

```css
.padre>a {
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <a href="#">Este enlace es un hijo directo</a>

  <div class="hijo">
    <a href="#">Este enlace NO es un hijo directo</a>
  </div>

  <a href="#">Este enlace es un hijo directo</a>
</div>
```

Como puedes observar, el primer y ultimo elemento `a` que se encuentran dentro de `.padre` son afectados por los estilos que declaramos; pero el elemento `a` en la 2da posicion no es afectado, por que no es un hijo directo de `.padre` ya que se encuentra dentro de otro elemento adicional.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que indica es que elija todos los nodos o elementos del `DOM` cuyo padre es un elemento que contiene una clase denominada `.grid`

**SELECTORES**

- `>` Indica que seleccionarás todos los elementos que tienen un padre específico

  - `div > a`: Selecciona todos los enlaces que se encuentran dentro de una etiqueta `div`
- `*` Señala seleccionar todos los elementos del DOM(aunque en este caso indica seleccionar todos los elementos que están dentro de otro elemento cuya clase es `.grid`)

  - `div > *`: Selecciona todos los elementos del árbol DOM que tengan como padre a una etiqueta `div`

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        .grid > * {
          color: red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="grid">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <span>Este span si es afectado por la regla del selector</span>
    </div>
      <p>Nuevo párrafo</p>
      <pre>Este fragmento de código</pre>
      <span>Este span no es afectado por la regla del selector</span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Vale recalcar que sólo se refiere a los elementos que son hijos *directos*, es decir, los elementos que se encuentre en segundo nivel ya no serán afectados por el selector